What happens if arguments alias the output buffer in std::format_to?
Consider the following example:
#include <format>
#include <print>

int main() {
    int x = 12345;
    // note: this is "awoo" followed by 28 zeros ([dcl.init.string] p3)
    char buffer[32] = "awoo";
    std::format_to(buffer, "{}{}", x, buffer);
    std::println("{}", buffer);
}

This code is expected to output 12345awoo because we are formatting {}{} with arguments 12345 and "awoo".
However, the actual output is 1234512345. The reason for this is obvious: Formating 12345 would write to the buffer, and so by the time that buffer (the second argument) is being handled by std::format_to, it no longer contains "awoo".
This begs the question: What is the expected result according to the C++ standard? https://eel.is/c++draft/format.functions#lib:vformat_to does not specify as a precondition that aliasing between the arguments and the output buffer isn't permitted, so I don't believe that this case is undefined behavior.

Using the same buffer as input source and output destination is considered undefined behaviour.

@OldBoy do you have a standard citation that supports that? It's certainly true for some functions such as std::memcpy, but it needs to state that in the function's preconditions. It's not the case unless otherwise stated.

The expected output (out of the box, order of evaluation) is 1234512345. More interesting is whether clint and such remark things. I wonder whether to_format's evaluation is required to add a terminating \0 when filling in buffer. When not the effect could be like "1234512345hu#+hi-.dfhd"

@JoopEggen to_format only takes an output iterator and has no knowledge of the rest of the buffer, so it cannot possibly write past the end of 1234512345 without risking segfaulting. Why do you think that the expected output is 1234512345? Is there some guarantee that the input arguments are processed one-by-one, left-to-right, and the output iterator is simultaneously being advanced?

@JoopEggen there's a bunch of \0s in buffer, so to_format doesn't need to add any

buffer could have contained "awoo\0u#+hi-.dfhd\0..." (32 places or seg fault) then the first int arg gives "12345u#+hi-.dfhd\0..." with output iterator at index 5, and then the final result.

@JoopEggen are we on the same page? In a different example, yes, there could hypothetically be awoo\0xzy..., but in this example, everything after awoo is zero-initialized (see https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.string#3).

@Caleth buffer is not normally filled with \0s (if there was no change made to the specs). Microsoft's compiler had the habit filling \0s

Okay I have to apologize to some people. @JanSchultke

It's unspecified, both 1234512345 and 12345awoo are conforming results.

The functions defined in [format.functions] use specializations of the class template formatter to format individual arguments.

[format.formatter.spec#1]
Thus the formatting of each argument happens within a separate function call to the others. There isn't any requirement on the order of these calls, so the side-effects are indeterminately sequenced with each other.

It is quite a stretch, but even sensible implementations could produce 12345awoo if it's unspecified behavior. It's not unthinkable that a super-optimized implementation, when given a std::uint8_t would "format" it via lookup table, loading the result into a register, so it wouldn't need to immediately write to the buffer. If it recognized that awoo is a short string, it could perhaps also load that into a register, concatenate the two strings within an xmm register via bit-shift, and then write everything using a single mov mem, xmm0 instruction.

Pretty sure the calls have to be made in order... how would you possibly know where to format the N+1st argument if you don't know how many bytes the first N arguments took (which, in general, you don't know)?

@Barry yes, look at the edit history of this answer. Most of the time you don't, but there might be situations where a clever compiler can save some cycles by doing it differently

@Caleth The clever compiler can't. The clever library... potentially could maybe in some very narrow situations with unclear benefit?

@Barry sorry, the clever implementation can

@Barry you sorta need to know how many characters the previous arguments took, but that doesn't mean that you have to write everything to the output buffer immediately. When formatting a bunch of std::uint8_t, you could also buffer the formatted bytes in registers, concatenate those into an xmm register, and do a single mov mem, xmm0 at the very end. In other words, the standard imposes no requirement on when the output iterator gets advanced and how this is sequenced in terms of the formatting of arguments. An implementation can utilize this, especially if that iterator is contiguous.

This is now LWG Issue 4078.
While the output is currently unspecified to be either 1234512345 or 12345awoo (as explained in @Caleth's answer), this case is also something that shouldn't work; i.e. it should be undefined behavior.
Similar functions such as sprintf have a char *restrict buffer parameter for output; they don't support aliasing between arguments and the output buffer. It's not reasonable for the user to expect it to work, and not reasonable for the implementation to support this use case.
At some point, std::format_to(buffer, "{}{}", x, buffer); is most likely going to be undefined behavior, however, this might take a long time because it's difficult to come up with wording which forbids this use case, and it's not a high priority issue.
